# How to style this select element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first attempt to convert PSD to HTML.

Below is screenshot of the the select element that I need to convert.

[image: actual design]

I tried using Bootstrap 3.0.3 and below is the result :

[image: result]

Anyone can help me?

Below is my HTML

```
<form id="bookingForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/pointA-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Pick up location" class="form-control input-lg" id="fromLoc" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/pointB-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Destination" class="form-control input-lg" id="toLoc" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/calendar-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM" class="form-control input-lg" id="calBooking" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/clock-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>
                        hr
                    </option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>
                        min
                    </option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>
                        AM
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Search for a fancy select jquery plugin

Comment: Try a component like this: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
Then you should be able to style it the way you need it to be.

Comment: @hunter cannot use pure css to achieve the result?

Comment: You won't be able to get exactly what you're going for by styling a `select` tag. Using some component like the one mentioned will give you more css control.

Comment: @hunter got it. maybe change to div instead?

Comment: If you check out that plugin it doesn't require that you change any of your existing `select` code. It hides that element and maintains its state. It replaces the viewable element with one that you are able to style.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea, 
You need to undisplay the drop-down arrow and replace it via a custom image.

**CSS**

```
.input-group select {
    background: url("http://www.invlocate.com/assets/images/arrow-10x10.gif") no-repeat right 5% bottom 40% #000;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: .25em;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 1% 15% 1% 4%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

[Here is a link to an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zQm3K/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS, but it not work on IE<9. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwcZU/

CSS:

```
select{
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
    background: url('http://veja0.abrilm.com.br/images/arrow-finances-down.png') no-repeat right center;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox-container;
    -khtml-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide your `<div class="col-md-6">` into 3 part by using three **'col-md-2'** class  eg:-`'<div class="col-md-2">'`

**Code:-**

```
<form id="bookingForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/pointA-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Pick up location" class="form-control input-lg" id="fromLoc" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/pointB-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Destination" class="form-control input-lg" id="toLoc" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/calendar-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM" class="form-control input-lg" id="calBooking" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <img src="/media/img/clock-grey.png" />
                </span>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>
                        hr
                    </option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>
                        min
                    </option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>
                        AM
                    </option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just replace <select...> with this <select class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">,hope it will help you.